# How to add an item to a memcached list atomically (in Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, memcached, atomic

Behold my simple Python memcached code below:

```
import memcache
memcache_client = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=True)
key = "myList"
obj = ["A", "B", "C"]
memcache_client.set(key, obj)
```

Now, suppose I want to append an element "D" to the list cached as `myList`, how can I do it atomically?

I know this is wrong because it is not atomic:

```
memcache_client.set(key, memcache_client.get(key) + ["D"])
```

The above statement contains a race condition. If another thread executes this same instruction at the exact right moment, one of the updates will get clobbered.

How can I solve this race condition? How can I update a list or dictionary stored in memcached atomically?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewCommands

Comment: Likely this is the answer, you should use `cas()` (check-and-set) instead of simple `set()`

Comment: which python memcache lib are you using?

Comment: @Anentropic: From my pip freeze: `python-memcached==1.53`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the corresponding function of the python client API

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_cas

Also here's a [nice tutorial](http://neopythonic.blogspot.ru/2011/08/compare-and-set-in-memcache.html) by Guido van Rossum. Hope he'd better explain python stuff than I ;)

Here's how the code should look like in your case:

```
memcache_client = memcache.Client(['127.0.0.1:11211'], debug=True)
key = "myList"
while True: # Retry loop, probably it should be limited to some reasonable retries
  obj = memcache_client.gets(key)
  assert obj is not None, 'Uninitialized object'
  if memcache_client.cas(key, obj + ["D"]):
    break
```

The whole workflow remains the same: first you fetch a value (w/ some internal information bound to a key), then modify the fetched value, then attempt to update it in the memcache. The only difference that the value (actually, key/value pair) is checked that it hasn't been changed simultaneosly from a parallel process. In the latter case the call fails and you should retry the workflow from the beginning. Also, if you have a multi-threaded application, then each memcache_client instance likely should be thread-local.

Also don't forget that there're incr() and decr() methods for simple integer counters which are "atomic" by their nature.

Comment: Can you please show how I should use the cas statement in my case above? The docs do not contain an example. Also, if possible show how to (in python) atomically add a key/value to a dictionary stored in memcached.

Comment: note `gets`/`cas` syntax is slightly different if using `pylibmc` http://sendapatch.se/projects/pylibmc/reference.html

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want receive a race condition then you must use Lock primitive from threading module. For example

```
lock = threading.Lock()

def thread_func():
    obj = get_obj()
    lock.acquire()
    memcache_client.set(key, obj)
    lock.release()
```

Comment: there is still race condition with _other_ clients of the memcache server

Comment: @Anentropic Saqib Ali asked about python threads not about multiple servers, so if he will use only one client with several threads my answer still valid.